# What does awaiting reviewers reply mean?

Tags: publications

What does awaiting reviewers reply mean? 
And how long does it take

Answer (score 0):

"Awaiting reviewers reply" means that your manuscript has been sent out for review.

There is no set time for this to take. Reviews can be returned to the editor within a few days, or it may take a couple of weeks depending on the journal.